# Can I modify a collection of collections when overriding .NET config files?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I have a question regarding the .NET configuration classes in the System.Configuration namespace. I am using .NET 4.0.

We have an application with an app.config file and the user of the application is able to provide a user.config file. The application uses a merged view of the configuration files using "ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration".

Question:

The configuration contains a configuration collection where the individual collection items also contain collections. In user.config I want to modify a configuration element inside one of the "inner" collections.

Example:

Let's say I have following snippet in an app.config file:

```
<Adapters>
    <Adapter Name='Adapter1' Type='Type1'>
        <Parameters>
            <add name='Parameter1' value='Value1' />
            <add name='Parameter2' value='Value2' />
            <add name='Parameter3' value='Value3' />
        </Parameters>
    </Adapter>
</Adapters>
```

Now I want to change Parameter3 to a different value in a user.config file:

```
<Adapters>
    <Adapter Name='Adapter1' Type='Type1'>
        <Parameters>
            <add name='Parameter3' value='NewValue3' />
        </Parameters>
    </Adapter>
</Adapters>
```

But with this config file I would get following exception:
"System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : The entry 'Adapter1' has already been added."

Following user.config approach works, but it is not so nice:

```
<Adapters>
    <remove Name='Adapter1' />
    <Adapter Name='Adapter1' Type='Type1'>
        <Parameters>
            <add name='Parameter1' value='Value1' />
            <add name='Parameter2' value='Value2' />
            <add name='Parameter3' value='NewValue3' />
        </Parameters>
    </Adapter>
</Adapters>
```

The reason why I don't like this approach is that you have to repeat Parameter1 and Parameter2 in the user.config file.
Every time a new parameter is introduced in app.config, I also have to add it in user.config.

Do you know a better solution?

The "Adapters" collection is defined in C# as follows:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(AdapterElement), AddItemName = "Adapter", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap)]
public class AdapterElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    ...
}

public class AdapterElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsKey = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["Name"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["Name"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Type")]
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["Type"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["Type"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Parameters")]
    public ConfigurableElementCollection Parameters
    {
        get
        {
            return (ConfigurableElementCollection)base["Parameters"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["Parameters"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the "Parameters" collection is defined as follows:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ConfigurableElement), CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap)]
public class ConfigurableElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    ...
}

public class ConfigurableElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["name"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["name"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("value")]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["value"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["value"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```